# How to convert String number to list of integers without whitespace?

Tags: python, string, list

please help me.

a = "7,5,1,3,2,6,4"

and I want it to be list of integers

a = [7,5,1,3,2,6,4]

I've tried

```
b = [int(x) for x in a.split(',')]
```

but this is the result (it has whitespace beetween)

a = [7, 5, 1, 3, 2, 6, 4]

How do I do it so I have my expected result?

Comment: The whitespace is just for representation in the python interpreter, it isn't clear what do you expect as the result

Comment: Why are you complaining about the spaces but not about the commas?

Answer (score 2):

No, it absolutely does NOT have whitespace in between.  What you get from that is a list of integers.  There are no strings, there is no whitespace.

Now, when you PRINT a list, Python separates the elements with "comma space" for easy readability, but the brackets, the commas, and the spaces are not part of the list.

Comment: Thank you so much and I am sorry for the dumb question, I am just so confused I thought it affected my function. I am just figure out that I have typo in my function.

Comment: For what it's worth, it is a very common problem to confuse the CONTENTS of one's data with the printed REPRESENTATION of that data.  So, don't feel bad, but dobe aware of this potential "gotcha".